# Find numeric substring with integers only

Tags: c++

The Question :

If the sequence of digits in X forms a substring of the sequence of digits in Y, it outputs "X is a substring of Y"; otherwise, if the sequence of digits in X forms a subsequence of the sequence of digits in Y, then it outputs "X is a subsequence of Y"; otherwise, it outputs "X is neither substring nor subsequence of Y".

**DO NOT** use arrays or strings in this program

The output should be as follows

---

Enter Y : 239847239

Enter X : 847

X is substring of Y

Enter Y : 239847239

Enter X : 3923

X is subsequence of Y

Enter Y : 239847239

Enter X : 489

X is neither substring nor subsequence of Y

---

And below is what I got so far... (haven't coded anything for subsequence as i was clueless)

I know my coding is very unefficient and is only suitble to use for the above model output. Any improvements or comments how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
  #include <cmath>
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;


int main() {
cout << "Enter Y: " ;
        int Y;
        cin >> Y;

cout << "Enter X: ";
        int X;
        cin >> X;

        if (Y >= X){               // Below are all the possibilities of substrings up to 9 decimal places.
                if( X == (Y % 10)) cout << "X is substring of Y";
                else if (X == (Y % 100)) cout << "X is substring of Y";
                else if (X == (Y % 1000)) cout << "X is substring of Y";
                else if (X == (Y % 10000)) cout << "X is substring of Y";
                else if (X == (Y % 100000)) cout << "X is substring of Y";
                else if (X == (Y % 1000000)) cout << "X is substring of Y";
                else if (X == (Y % 10000000)) cout << "X is substring of Y";
                else if (X == (Y % 100000000)) cout << "X is substring of Y";
                else if (X == (Y % 1000000000)) cout << "X is substring of Y";

                else    cout << "X is neither substring nor subsequence of Y";
        }
        else cout << "neither subsequence nor subset"; // prints out when  Y is less than X.
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Are you allowed to use recursion?

Comment: You'll never get a general solution that way; it can't find 12 in 123. I see three options: 1) write your own stripped-down string class, 2) brute force recursion (effective but crude) and 3) a more subtle (and efficient) recursion based on `Y /= 10`.

Comment: yea recursion is allowed

Comment: Just to clarify, what does `subsequence` means? I guess 135 is subsequence of 12345 because 1,3 and 5 are in 12345 in that specific order, but not consecutive, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

This what i got by far:

**Substring**

```
bool substring(long x, long y){
    double auxX = x;
    int power = 0;
    while (auxX >= 1){
        auxX /= 10;
        ++power;
    }

    int mask = pow(10, power);

    int reminder;
    while (y > 0){
        reminder = y % mask;
        if (reminder == x){
            return true;
        }
        y /= 10;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Subsequence**

```
bool subsequence(long x, long y){
    int lastX;
    int lastY;
    while (y > 0){
        lastX = x % 10;
        lastY = y % 10;
        if (lastX == lastY){
            x /= 10;
            if (x <= 0){
                return true;
            }
        }
        y /= 10;
    }

    return false;
}
```

**Main**

```
int main()
{
    long x = 21;
    long y = 469721481;

    if (substring(x, y)){
        cout << x << " is substring of " << y << std::endl;
    }
    else if (subsequence(x, y)){
        cout << x << " is subsequence of " << y << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << x << " is neither substring nor subsquence of " << y << std::endl;  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tested some cases and it seems to work fine, but you **should** test with edge cases (multiple repetitions of the same pattern, one digit numbers, zeros, etc) and retouch this snippet